# PHP: Decoding of base64 encoded IMAP body

Tags: php, imap, decoding

PHP -IMAP
I have saved all imap mail to database and displaying them from database. My problem is that one mail is showing "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64". If i base64 decode it then other mails also get affected. I haven't been able to change it to human readable format till yet. Any help will be highly appreciated.
I have tried many solution but The code currently I am using is,

```
mb_convert_encoding($body, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");
```

The output of this mail is

```
------=_NextPart_001_0606_012497BF.12408D60
Content-Type: text/plain;
charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

 OTA5MTU5Mzg3DQoNCuS7juaKgOacr+i1sOWQkeeuoeeQhueahOWbm+S4quaguOW/gw0KMjAxMi05
 LTE1ICAxNjowMjoxNw==

 ------=_NextPart_001_0606_012497BF.12408D60
 Content-Type: text/html;
charset="utf-8"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

 PCFET0NUWVBFIEhUTUwgUFVCTElDICItLy9XM0MvL0RURCBIVE1MIDQuMCBUcmFuc2l0aW9uYWwv
 L0VOIj4NCjxIVE1MPjxIRUFEPg0KPE1FVEEgY29udGVudD0idGV4dC9odG1sOyBjaGFyc2V0PXV0
 Zi04IiBodHRwLWVxdWl2PUNvbnRlbnQtVHlwZT4NCjxNRVRBIG5hbWU9R0VORVJBVE9SIGNvbnRl
 bnQ9Ik1TSFRNTCA4LjAwLjYwMDEuMTg5OTkiPjwvSEVBRD4NCjxCT0RZPg0KPFA+PEZPTlQgc2l6
 ZT0yPjkwOTE1OTM4NzxCUj48QlI+5LuO5oqA5pyv6LWw5ZCR566h55CG55qE5Zub5Liq5qC45b+D
 PC9GT05UPjwvUD4NCjxQPjxGT05UIHNpemU9Mj4yMDEyLTktMTUmbmJzcDsgMTY6MDI6MTc8L0ZP
 TlQ+PC9QPjwvQk9EWT48L0hUTUw+DQo=

 ------=_NextPart_001_0606_012497BF.12408D60--
```

Comment: Maybe this post could help you:
**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539902/php-imap-decoding-messages**

Answer (score 0):

It's base64, you have to use base64_decode on body part like this:

```
base64_decode('OTA5MTU5Mzg3DQoNCuS7juaKgOacr+i1sOWQkeeuoeeQhueahOWbm+S4quaguOW/gw0KMjAxMi05LTE1ICAxNjowMjoxNw==');
```

Comment: yes i have used base64_decode(not base64 decode) but it still doesn't show the required result. Actually it shows some symbol.

Comment: This is the output of base64_decode

5m=MtNn=u?<{^^?rn{^j{z'rb?909159387

????????????
2012-9-15  16:02:17^?4NMv]*'O*^mfZ?
z{S}?xj?=
QeA!Q50AU 1%\Q!Q50?Q???84(!Q50!4(5Q????????
??Q4(5Q9IQ=H?5M!Q50?!4( =d4(@=9P? H H;*r�BGBjno?=9P@4(@=9P???=9P@ =d!Q504(5m=MtNn=u?<

Comment: This is what I'm getting by base64_decode, a number, a date and some Chinese words: `909159387

从技术走向管理的四个核心

2012-9-15  16:02:17` Translation of Chinese words is: `From the technical to the management of the four core`

Answer (score -4):

just to manually check there are several online services like
http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

just copy and paste the base64 source and choose "decode". You will get a "human readyble format".