# php problems decoding email content when using the Euro sign

Tags: php, imap

I'm having problems receiving utf8 reading emails via php (5.3) when they include special characters such as the euro sign.

I'm aware I should be using a test on $structure->encoding=3 for UTF8 (as seen in [PHP IMAP decoding messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539902/php-imap-decoding-messages)), etc, but to boil this specific problem down to its raw state I've created the following simple testbed using the email header taken from an email sent from Outlook to myself - and using this encoded message - I've tried to parse it via PHP onto a simple HTML output - but instead of seeing my special characters as they were, I see question marks (?) instead.

Testbed:

```
<?php
echo "<HTML><BODY>";

$v1=" =?utf-8?B?Rlc6IFRlc3QgQ2hhcmFjdGVycyBpbiB0aGUgU3ViamVjdCA6IMOY4oKswqU=?= =?utf-8?B?x5nDpg==?=";

echo "A=".utf8_decode(imap_utf8($v1));

echo "</BODY></HTML>";
?>
```

Output:

```
A= FW: Test Characters in the Subject : Ø?¥U??æ
```

BUT I was expecting

```
A=FW: Test Characters in the Subject : Ø€¥Ǚæ
```

.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

A

Comment: Does your HTML page have the proper encoding?  (utf-8)?

Comment: Don't think page encoding would matter here - but do you have a suggestion on what meta tag I could add to rule it out; note, I've taken the same results through to a database - and the database is showing the same problems