# PHP Imap Body Decode Issue

Tags: php, imap

I have copied the following code from [PHP IMAP decoding messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539902/php-imap-decoding-messages), but I am still struggling with the implementation. This is how I have implemented this:

```
public function readMessage($imap,$email_number){

    $message['header'] = imap_headerinfo($imap,$email_number,0);
    $message['overview'] = imap_fetch_overview($imap,$email_number,0);
    //$message['body'] = imap_fetchbody($imap,$email_number,2);

    // Get the message body.
    $body = imap_fetchbody($imap, $email_number, 1.2);
    if (!strlen($body) > 0) {
        $body = imap_fetchbody($imap, $email_number, 1);
    }

    // Get the message body encoding.
    $encoding = $this->getEncodingType($imap,$email_number);

    // Decode body into plaintext (8bit, 7bit, and binary are exempt).
    if ($encoding == 'BASE64') {
        $message['body'] = $this->decodeBase64($body);
    }
    elseif ($encoding == 'QUOTED-PRINTABLE') {
        $message['body'] = $this->decodeQuotedPrintable($body);
    }
    elseif ($encoding == '8BIT') {
        $message['body'] = $this->decode8Bit($body);
    }
    elseif ($encoding == '7BIT') {
        $message['body'] = $this->decode7Bit($body);
    }

    return $message;
}
```

For some reason the getEncodingType call always returns the format as 7bit which causes issues when displaying the text and shows garbage. Here is that function:

```
public function getEncodingType($imap, $messageId, $numeric = false) {
    // See imap_fetchstructure() documentation for explanation.
    $encodings = array(
      0 => '7BIT',
      1 => '8BIT',
      2 => 'BINARY',
      3 => 'BASE64',
      4 => 'QUOTED-PRINTABLE',
      5 => 'OTHER',
    );
    // Get the structure of the message.
    $structure = $this->getStructure($imap, $messageId);
    // Return a number or a string, depending on the $numeric value.
    if ($numeric) {
        return $structure->encoding;
    } else {
        return $encodings[$structure->encoding];
    }
}
```

Can you perhaps point out a few things that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry for stupid variable names it was from my high school years. I have updated my answer, please take a look again.

Answer (score 0):

Use [imap_qprint](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-qprint.php):

```
<?php

$header = imap_header($imap, $email_number);
$from = $header->from;
$print_sender = $from[0]->personal;
$print_check = $print_sender[0]->charset;

$bodymsg = imap_qprint(imap_fetchbody($imap, $email_number, 1.2));

if (empty($bodymsg)) {
    $bodymsg = imap_qprint(imap_fetchbody($imap, $email_number, 1));
}

if($print_check == "ISO-8859-9" ) {
    $print_sender = mb_convert_encoding($print_sender, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-9");//Encoding process
    $bodymsg = mb_convert_encoding($bodymsg, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-9");//Encoding process
}

echo $print_sender;
echo $bodymsg;

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, your code does convert the content, but it does not retain the formatting, it seems to convert it to text only.

Comment: Perhaps it is not in part 1.2 :)

Comment: @LeRoux try not to include `mb_convert_encoding` part?