# IMAP body displaying raw data

Tags: php, imap

I'm using php imap functiona to get mail content.

Following is my code:

```
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = $_REQUEST['email'];
$password = $_REQUEST['pwd'];
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

if($emails) {   
    $output = '';
    rsort($emails);

    $i = 0;
    foreach($emails as $email_number) 
    {       
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        $message =  imap_qprint(imap_body($inbox, $email_number)); 
    }
}
```

Displaying html data as it is in my mail body along with some raw data. How can I remove this.

```
--94eb2c03a0feeaad70054df6411a
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=fowed; delsp=yes
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539902/php-imap-decoding-messages?rq=1

Comment: @RamRaider Thx, It's usefull.