# how to read body of imap and attachment both in php with encoding?

Tags: php, imap, php-imap

I have reading mail from IMAP in php.

when i reading mail from IMAP it works fine.

But when mail is with attachment then message body is unreadable however attachment downloading working fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP IMAP decoding messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539902/php-imap-decoding-messages)

Comment: no this logic is not working when mail has attachments

Comment: check the encoding type of the content text a normall text email does not use multipart encoding but attached emails do but with the attachment there are mime types and text encoding it could be your text is received as UTF16 and you need it in UTF8.